# How do I subtract/divide/multiply a list of numbers

Tags: python

I am working on a calculator and this is my progress.
(Note: I want to support more than 2 variables.)
I am stuck on how to do the subtraction, multiplication and division part.

```
numbers=[]
count=int(input("How many Numbers\n"))
operation=input("(*), (/), (+), (-) ")
for i in range(count):
  num=int(input("Number :"))
  numbers.append(num)
answer=sum(numbers)
print(answer)
```

Comment: The code needs an if/elif to determine the operation. Then perform the operation that the user inputs.

Comment: You ask the user to input an *operation* but you don't do anything with it

Comment: Hey JCaesar I was willing to make a calculator and I was confused on how to do the other operations

Answer (score 0):

To build a dynamic calculator, use the below function, but be aware for division we need only two values(denominator and numerator), so supplying multiple values will not make sense for division.

once you create this function, you can supply as many numbers as you want to perform addition, subtraction and multiplication.

```
def calculator(*nums):
    a = 0
    op = input(" For Addition, supply (+), For Subtraction, supply (-), For Multiplication, supply(*)")
    for i in nums:
        if op == "+":
            a += i
        elif op == "-":
            a -= i
        elif op == "*":
            a *= i
    return a
```

**Calling the Function**

```
calculator(10,20,30)
```

For Addition, supply (+), For Subtraction, supply (-), For Multiplication, supply(*)

If you supply +, your output will be,

**Output:**
60